# global name 'estadis' is not defined

Tags: python, django

views.py:

```
@login_required
def ListEspeci(request, id_especialidad):
  especialidad = Especialidad.objects.get(id=id_especialidad) 

  if request.method == 'GET':
    if estadis ==  Especialidad.objects.filter(estadistica=0):
      form = EstadisticaForm(request.POST, instance=especialidad)

      if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

      return HttpResponseRedirect('/solicitar/lista/%s/' % id_especialidad)

    return render(request, 'estadis.html', {'form':form})
    if estadis ==  Especialidad.objects.filter(estadistica > 0):
    pedido = Pedido.objects.filter(especialidad=especialidad)

    return render(request, 'index2.html', {'pedido':pedido, 'especialidad':especialidad})
```

models.py:

```
class Especialidad(models.Model):
nombre        = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
estadistica   = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
encargado     = models.ForeignKey('Encargado', blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

First I capture the id of the Specialty model, then I believe in the conditional if, if the statistical field of the specialty is equal to 0, it sends me a template of the model form to enter the quantity, and otherwise it passes the template where a table.

Maybe I have not formulated well the sight for the desired logic, some help? please

Comment: is variable `estadis`  a global one? i didnt see it defined

Comment: I fixed your indentation. Can you run that and let me know if you are still getting an error?

Comment: yes! global name 'estadis' is not defined, update view!

Comment: Can you post the stack trace instead of annotating the code? Its usually the better way to spot the problem.

Comment: Update the code suggested by @user2896976 and the title for the new error, 
Any suggestions sir?

Comment: What is `estadis` supposed to contain? It would help if you could include some comments in your code for those of us who don't understand spanish, it's easier to debug when you know what it's supposed to do.

Comment: yes! Good statistics is a variable that created in the same view, contains the model "Especialidad" and filters the field "estadistica" with conditional if = 0, I do not know how to raise it but I could not say more!

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement has a single equals instead of a double, and is missing a colon:

```
if estadis =  Especialidad.objects.filter(estadistica=0)
```

to

```
if estadis == Especialidad.objects.filter(estadistica=0):
```

Comment: @DemaroCreate Missed something, updated. You need a colon as well

Comment: I did not understand your comment

Comment: Thanks for your help, now the error is on line 227, updated the number

Comment: global name 'estadis' is not defined, master?

Answer (score -1):

Your Code seems to have two issues -

1. Indentation : In Python Code blocks are recognized based on the indentation, so they should be consistent. You seems to have different indentation for different blocks(single space at line ater #221, double space and tab space), no indentation after function declaration. You can use tab indentation everywhere.
2. The statements in python starts a new block with ':' at the end and the next line is indented. So in your case if-statements will need ':' at the end.